# how to determine which row is the exact registration id from the FCM result when i have more results than i have send

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

normally this should be simple but i don't fully understand which one is the exact row.
I've send and fcm message to say 17 registrations, but in the answer from FCM there are 18 results in total. 16 OK send, 1 Error, 1 canonical.

```
    {"multicast_id":6541496712341791234,"success":16,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":1,"results":

So:
1 to 3 are send ok {messageid:..
4th is {"error":"NotRegistered"},
10 times again ok {messageid:...
1 time a canonical
3 times ok again {messageid:.....

So 17 send, 18 results received.
```

So now i can't simply count which id is belonging to what. ok the 4th is simple and it should be deleted, but the canonical one is i think the culprit. Is it on itself or does it belong to the OK send id just before the canonical?

I need to know so i can update the correct id in the database.

I hope you understand.
Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: I gave a quick answer on which one is canonical. But I'm not sure I understand what your really asking. Are you sure this isn't an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

The ID that FCM answered `canonical` for is the 15th in your list of 18 IDs. At least that's the only way that I can get it to add up to 18.

Comment: Sorry, i did not respond earlier, i did not get any notification of responds. Yes it is the 15th of the 18 i received. The question is if it is related to the 14th send token-id?